# Rails 4: Conditional check set of values returned via many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My application has a user model, role model and assignment model. There is many to many relationship between user and role model through assignment model. I want to check if current user has particular role_id. Have can this be done?

My Model Classes are as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ruby
current_user.role_ids.include?(role_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the roles IDs of a user using the `#role_ids` methods. It will return an array of the ids, e.g.

```
user = User.first
user.role_ids
```

Given that, you can easily check if an id exists in the array, e.g.

```
user.role_ids.include?(1)
```

Also, check out the rails guide on other methods you get when using a [has_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Use the has_many :through association by asking its [association_name]_ids

```
    User.first.role_ids.include? particular_role_id
```

will generate SQL like:

```
    SELECT `roles`.id FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `assignments_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `assignments_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `assignments_roles`.`user_id` = 1
```

Please read the API doc @ [APIdoc ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods#has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) for ongoing details

Comment: You could provide a link to the docs to for others to refer to. :D